# Web Browser in .NET. Browser setting

Tags: c#, .net, browser

I have created a web browser in .NET [c#]. It is working fine but I am little confused with how to manage these things.. please help me in deciding how to implement it!

1. Where/How the cookies will be stored in my browser?
2. Bookmark?
3. History?
4. Pop Up blocker / other browser settings?

I can understand that the question is too general, but even your little suggestion will help me a lot.

Comment: Do you use the `WebBrowser` Control? Because that is just the IE that is installed on your computer and therefore uses the IE settings for the items that you list.

Comment: @Bazzz Thanks for quick response. Yes I am using WebBrowser control and the same I saw that it is fetching the settings of IE. How to customize the setting for my broswer which will not affect the IE settings?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can have seperate settings for IE and for the WebBrowser control, in the end the control is merely a wrapper for the ActiveX that provides an IE instance in your form. So deep inside it just is IE. Perhaps you can keep a set of settings that can override IE's settings after loading the control. I would start looking here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx

Comment: @Bazzz: Put the last comment into an answer because it is a valid answer and should be awarded acceptance (and some votes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Look at how other browsers handle cookies, they store it in the browsers temp (cache) folder
2. Bookmarks are just a key value list (at the very simpliest), key is a URL, value is the display name. Any place you can store a key/value list (like a database) would work.
3. History is just bookmarks that are automatically captured and ordered by date.
4. This depends on what you are using for the web browser control - if you are using the IE activeX control then you are stuck to sharing settings with it. This also means that you have a fantastic UI built for the settings though. If you have written your own then you need to store them somewhere, in a database for example.

I have mentioned database a few times, but I am not thinking a full MS SQL Server install, but rather something like SQLite.